# Backbone Model gives this.set not a function in Model.initialize

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette, backbone-events, backbone-model

I've a model listen on the vent for a event `update:TotalCost`, which is triggered from (unrelated) Collection C when any model M belonging to collection C changes.

This event is coded in the initialize method as below. On receiving the event I get the following error:

> **TypeError: this.set is not a function**
> this.set({ "totalsale": value});

```
CostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({     
  defaults: {
    totalSale: 0,
    totalTax: 0
  },

  initialize: function(attrs, options) {
    if(options) {
      if(options.vent) {
        this.vent = options.vent;
      }
    }
            
    this.vent.on("update:TotalCost", function(value) {
      this.set({ "totalSale": value}); **//ERROR HERE**
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using a closure?

```
CostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({     
  defaults: {
    totalSale: 0,
    totalTax: 0
  },
  initialize: function(attrs, options) {
    var self = this;

    if(options) {
      if(options.vent) {
        this.vent = options.vent;
      }
    }

    this.vent.on("update:TotalCost", function(value) {
      self.set({ "totalSale": value}); 
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this works!  I just checked in firebug before using closure above, 'this' is actually the window object! I so surely assumed that 'this' would be the model instance! Any clues on why reference to 'this' is now Window

Comment: Hard to say without seeing how you instantiate the model.  If you share your code I will fiddle it and try and see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for offering to help out, alas, easier said then done as lots of other dependent components and layout/regions for me to make a clean cut of workable code for fiddle! :(

Answer (score 12):

It is highly possible you've forgot to add the `new` keyword before your model for example you have:

```
var user = UserModel();

// instead of 

var user = new UserModel();
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want `this` to refer to current `CostModel` instance, to do so you need to pass `this` to `this.vent.on` call so event callback will be executed in context of model:

```
this.vent.on("update:TotalCost", function(value) {
    this.set({ "totalSale": value});
}, this);
```

Comment: I tried adding 'this' as the 3rd. But still getting same error. Do I need to use any _.bind calls for this to work? My knowledge about using bind is very sketchy.

Comment: Have you tried to set breakpoint in the event body and check what is `this`?

Comment: Yes, I just checked in firebug, 'this' is actually the window object! I so surely assumed that 'this' would be the model instance! Any clues on why reference to 'this' is now Window

Comment: What is `this.vent`? In either way if its backbone view, model or collection, `this` is supposed to refer to that instance, not window.

Comment: vent is event aggregation provided by Marionette backbone plugin. see: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md#appvent-event-aggregator

Comment: I see it [uses Backbone.Events mixin](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr/blob/master/src/wreqr.eventaggregator.js), so `vent.on` should accept context as the 3rd argument. Got no clue why its not working.

Answer (score 1):

it may be due to **'set'** works on **model** not on **object**. so you can, first convert your object in to model then try..

in example:

```
new Backbone.Model(your_object).set('val', var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this error can be if you try to create a new model without using the "new" keyword

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this mysterious error when using it with Parse. I had:

```
Parse.User().current().escape("facebookID")
```

... when I should have had:

```
Parse.User.current().escape("facebookID")
```

Removed the extra () and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause:

```
// render() method in view object
setInterval(this.model.showName, 3000);

// showName() method in model object
showName: function(){
    console.log(this.get('name')); // this.get is not a function
}
```